# How to make an object with a default value with it's not passed to the class?

Tags: ruby, class, object

I'm trying to make an object within the class Produto with a default value of "Geral" when there's no input for the variable categoria, but I'm having some trouble understanding what is wrong with this challenge, I've been searching for a more in depth class about object oriented but got no clues about what I should change for it to work, I'm really sorry if it's a dumb question.

```
categoria.rb

require 'produto'
class Categoria 
  attr_accessor :nome
  def initialize(nome: 'Geral')
    @nome = nome
  end
end
```

```
class Produto 
  attr_accessor :nome, :categoria, :preco, :estoque
  def initialize(nome: 'Sem nome', categoria: categoria , preco: '0', estoque: '0')
    @nome = nome
    @preco = preco
    @categoria = categoria
    @estoque = estoque
  end

  def adiciona_estoque(quantidade)
    @estoque += quantidade
  end

  def remove_estoque(quantidade)
    @estoque -= quantidade
  end
end
```

```
spec.rb

  it "deveria criar um objeto de categoria Geral por padrão" do
    nome = 'Teclado'
    preco = 100
    estoque = 3
    produto = Produto.new(nome: nome, preco: preco, estoque: estoque)

    expect(produto.nome).to eq 'Teclado'
    expect(produto.categoria.nome).to eq 'Geral'
    expect(produto.preco).to eq 100
    expect(produto.estoque).to eq 3
  end
```

rspec output

```
Produto deveria criar um objeto de categoria Geral por padrão
    Failure/Error: expect(produto.categoria.nome).to eq 'Geral'

    NoMethodError:
      undefined method `nome' for nil:NilClass
    # ./spec/1_produto_spec.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: `@categoria = categoria` => `@categoria = categoria || Categoria.new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:
You need to change

```rb
def initialize(nome: 'Sem nome', categoria: categoria , preco: '0', estoque: '0')
  @nome = nome
  @preco = preco
  @categoria = categoria
  @estoque = estoque
end
```

to

```rb
def initialize(nome: 'Sem nome', categoria: categoria , preco: '0', estoque: '0')
  @nome = nome
  @preco = preco
  @categoria = categoria || Categoria.new
  @estoque = estoque
end
```

Long answer:
Problem that `attr_accessor :categoria` is the same as

```rb
def categoria
  @categoria
end

def categoria=(val)
  @categoria = val
end
```

it mean that when you not setting `categoria` in `Produto.new` it takes `@categoria` that is equal to `nil`.

Comment: @GuilhermeLuiz no problems :) You can mark answer as correct if it's helped you :)

Comment: "[What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773)"
and "[Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994)"

Answer (score 1):

If you try to run the code verbatim in your class definition of `Produto` you'll notice the output

```
warning: circular argument reference - categoria
```

This is the first clue. Also, you'll notice that `Categoria#nome` is an instance method. That means you'll have to be dealing with an instance of that class to successfully make that method call.

Try modifying your `Produto` initializer parameters to make sure you are actually defaulting to giving it an instance of `Categoria` (instead of `categoria` which, unless you pass in a value, will be `nil`). For example:

```rb
class Categoria
  ...
  def initialize(nome: 'Sem nome', categoria: Categoria.new , preco: '0', estoque: '0')
    @nome = nome
    @preco = preco
    @categoria = categoria
    @estoque = estoque
  end
  ...
end
```

After making that change, you should see that (within your test block) `produto.categoria.nome` returns "Geral".